# Polar coordinates, bounded domain with $C^{1}$ boundary

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

I have a question about a integral on a surface.

It is well known that for any Integrable function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, it holds that
\begin{equation}
(1) \quad \frac{d}{dr} \int_{B(0,r)}f\,dm=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}f\,d \sigma \quad m\text{-a.e. }r.
\end{equation}
Here and hereafter $m$ denotes the $n$-dim Lebesgue measure, $\sigma$ the $(n-1)$ dim Hausdorff measure (surface measure) and $B(0,r)$ the open ball of radius $r$ centered at origin[See Lawrence C. Evans and Ronald E. Gariepy's book].

**Question**

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a bounded domain with $C^{1}$ boundary. Set 
\begin{align}
D_{\epsilon}=\left\{ x \in \bar{D} : d\left(x,\partial D \right) \leq \epsilon \right\}
\end{align}
Can we show the following equation? :
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{D_{\epsilon}}f\,dm=\int_{\partial D}f\,d\sigma ,\quad (f \in C(\bar{D}))
\end{align}

This is a generalization of $(1)$.

If you know how to prove this equation or helpful references, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know the coarea formula?

Comment: Yes. (1) is a corollary of the coarea formula.

Comment: There are much more general statements of the coarea formula that ought to essentially deal with the second case too.